# python-3.7 build from source, pip not being installed in altroot/DESTDIR

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have a custom linux distribution, and am building python 3.7.2 from source.  The build is configured to install into an alternate root directory, from which it will be packaged for installation.

This process works fine when run on a system that does not yet have python3 installed.  But, when I run the same build process on a host that has a previously built copy of the same package on it, ensurepip fails to install pip or setuptools into the alternate installation directory, because it finds them on the system itself.

Software is extracted and configure called as follows:

```
mkdir -p /data/buildspace/work/python3-x86_64
/bin/tar xf /data/sources/python3/Python-3.7.2.tgz \
     -C /data/buildspace/work/python3-x86_64
( cd /data/buildspace/work/python3-x86_64/Python-3.7.2 ; \
     [ -f ./configure ] && CC="gcc" CXX="g++" ./configure \
     --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib
     --sysconfdir=/etc --bindir=/usr/bin  || echo "No './configure' script")
```

Then `make install` is called with DESTDIR specified:

```
make -C /data/buildspace/work/python3-x86_64/Python-3.7.2
    install DESTDIR=/data/buildspace/work/python3-x86_64/root
```

When building initially, before the build system has python3 installed, I see in the build output/log:

```
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
    case upgrade in \
            upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
            install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
    esac; \
     ./python -E -m ensurepip \
            $ensurepip --root=/data/buildspace/work/python3-x86_64/root/ ; \
fi
Looking in links: /tmp/tmpa9_lumsc
Collecting setuptools
Collecting pip
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
Successfully installed pip-18.1 setuptools-40.6.2
```

However, when building on a system that has python3 installed, I can't find any way to prevent it from considering the pip in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages.  Running the same configure will yield:

```
Looking in links: /tmp/tmp086yebrw
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (40.6.2)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (18.1)
```

Then, I tried `--with-ensurepip=install`, but that only changed the output slightly:

```
Looking in links: /tmp/tmpl0x88vr9
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (40.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (18.1)
```

I don't know if this is a bug in ensurepip, where it should not consider the default python library directory when run with `--root` specified, or if there is something I'm missing for this "install into a whole new space".

I looked at the idea of using **venv**, but I want the resulting binaries to be able to run in normal locations on the system after package and install, so I think that may be the wrong direction.

Appreciate any pointers.  Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve it ?

Comment: Also interested here

Comment: I have the same situation.  I already have another version of python installed.  When I am building from source for a second version of python, ensurepip finds that I have pip elsewhere from my first version and therefore will not install it.  The result is that pip is missing from the second version and the script I am using which depends upon it being present in the second version fails.  Referencing the original version of pip does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's three years later, no answer was provided, and [this bug has existed within ensurepip since 2015](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3063), so for posterity's sake, I figured I'd share the solution that worked for me:

Use [get-pip](https://github.com/pypa/get-pip) instead, and pass the `--ignore-installed` flag when calling `get-pip.py` to prevent overwriting a preexisting system installed pip.

```
$ cd <python_bin_dir>
$ curl -sSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py --ignore-installed
```